# load multiple namespaces grouped in one backend call via i18next react

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

We have a react project using i18next.
The app uses labels grouped in +20 namespaces.
This works like it should, but now we are implementing a backend system to load translations instead of static .json files.

This result, like you would expect in +20 calls being made to retreive the translations.
Now, we had the idea to group all those namespaces into one bigger backend call.
This would return te translations into this format and be more performant then 20 separated files.

```
{
 "namespace_1: {
  "key1.1": "label1.1",
  "key1.2": "label1.2"
 },
 "namespace_2: {
  "key2.1": "label2.1",
  "key2.2": "label2.2"
 },
 ...
}
```

i18n options like i have it now

```
const i18nInitOptions = {
  ns: ['basics'],
  lng: defaultLang,
  fallbackLng: false,
  defaultNS: 'basics',
  load: 'currentOnly',
  returnObjects: true,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
  appendNamespaceToMissingKey: true,
  backend: {
    loadPath: ([language], [namespace]) =>
      backEndURL
        ? ${cmsTranslationsUrl}/${language}
        : `/i18n/${language}/${namespace}.json`;,
  },
};
```

Now i wanted to find out how i could make this work without the need of changeing the label usage.
So i want to keep the ´t("NAMESPACE.labelkey")´

Would any of you have an idea how i could achieve this?

I already checked out the parse option after loadpath in backend options.
Was able to load the single backend labels, list. But not to use them in a correct way.